# neovim: no module named __future__

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, neovim, pyenv

When I try to open certain python files in neovim, I get an error:

```
"pool.py" 667L, 25276C
function provider#python#Call[9]..remote#host#Require[10]..provider#pythonx#Require, line 15
Vim(if):ch 1 was closed by the client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/neovim2/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 67, in <module>
    import os
  File "./os.py", line 44, in <module>
    from __future__ import absolute_import
ImportError: No module named __future__
Failed to load python host. You can try to see what happened by starting nvim with $NVIM_PYTHON_LOG_FILE set and opening the generated log file. Also
, the host stderr is available in messages.
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

This happens any time I open a python file in a directory that contains an `os.py` or `os.pyc` file.  It looks like neovim is trying to import the local os.py file instead of the one in the virtualenv.

What can I do about this?

EDIT: turns out it's not when I open a file in the same directory as an `os.py` file, it's when I open a file anywhere while the current working directory has an `os.py` file.  Basically, it looks like python is checking the local directory for imports before checking the python libs.

Comment: Why do you have a file named `os.py`??????

Comment: [_I_ don't](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/src/gevent/os.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The problem was with my `$PYTHONPATH`.  I had in my `.bashrc` file this:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:~/.local/lib/python"
```

The problem was that, when that line is executed, `$PYTHONPATH` is empty, leading to the string starting with a `:`.  I'm not 100% sure why, but that resulted in python checking the local directory for a module BEFORE checking the python libraries.

I changed it to

```
if [ -z "$PYTHONPATH" ]; then
  export PYTHONPATH="~/.local/lib/python"
else
  export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:~/.local/lib/python"
fi
```

And now it works.